# remove() function not deleting the item within ul list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-2

I have created a javascript function on drop down select it adds element and calculate the total amount of the added product now what I want do here is to make a function to delete that product added from the dropdown list but when I click on delete button it us only deleting the selected button and not deleting the row which I want it to be deleted by clicking on the button. You can review on this fiddle and will understood what is going on with it https://jsfiddle.net/h1k6mohs/ and also my script is not working may be is because it is not calling to that function below is my php script file

Controller 
Home.php

```
public function addpart() {
            $part        = $this->input->post('parts');
            $part_modify = explode(")", $part);
            $part_id     = $part_modify[0];
            $old_price   = $this->input->post('old_price');
            $old_minutes = $this->input->post('old_minutes');
            $data        = $this->get_data->data_cart($part_id, $old_price, $old_minutes);
            echo $data;
        }

        public function removepart() {
            $part_id     = $this->input->post('partid');
            $old_price   = $this->input->post('old_price');
            $old_minutes = $this->input->post('old_minutes');
            $data        = $this->get_data->delete_part($part_id, $old_price, $old_minutes);
            echo $data;
        }
```

Model
Get_data.php

```
public function data_cart($part_id, $old_price, $old_minutes) {
        $get_data = $this->db->get_where('rapair_parts', array('id' => $part_id));
        $total_minutes = $get_data->row()->repair_time + $old_minutes;
        $total_price   = $get_data->row()->part_price + $old_price;

        $html  = '<div class="col-xs-12">';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">Repair time</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">'.$total_minutes.' mins</div></div>';
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" id="minutes_parts" value="'.$total_minutes.'" />';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-12">';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">Discount</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">'."&pound;".'0.00</div></div>';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-12">';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">Total</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">&pound;'.$total_price.'</div></div>';
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" id="price_parts" value="'.$total_price.'" />';

        return $html;
    }

    public function delete_part($part_id, $old_price, $old_minutes) {
        $get_data = $this->db->get_where('rapair_parts', array('id' => $part_id));
        $total_minutes = $get_data->row()->repair_time - $old_minutes;
        $total_price   = $get_data->row()->part_price - $old_price;

        $html  = '<div class="col-xs-12">';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">Repair time</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">'.$total_minutes.' mins</div></div>';
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" id="minutes_parts" value="'.$total_minutes.'" />';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-12">';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">Discount</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">'."&pound;".'0.00</div></div>';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-12">';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">Total</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="col-xs-6">&pound;'.$total_price.'</div></div>';
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" id="price_parts" value="'.$total_price.'" />';

        return $html;
    }
```

Please help me out with this bug please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements in Chrome have a .remove() method which allows for self-removal of an element instead of having to do it from the parent.

So "remove" is a reserved keyword, that's the issue and the reason it removes the element and not executing your function. You need to choose another name for your function.

Comment: Thank you your advise worked for me though i just changed my function name and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I gone through your code, as per code you are using remove() which is inbuilt in JQuery, so you can directly apply to the HTML, kindly follow the below code.

```
<div id="js-part">
  <li id="parts3" style="display: list-item;" onclick="remove();">
    <div class="col-md-9"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Wifi Antenna</div>
    <div class="col-d-3"><a>Remove</a></div>
  </li>
  <li id="parts1" style="display: list-item;" onclick="remove();">
    <div class="col-md-9"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Glass Screen</div>
    <div class="col-d-3"><a >Remove</a></div>
  </li>
  <li id="parts4" style="display: list-item;" onclick="remove();">
    <div class="col-md-9"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Rear Camera</div>
    <div class="col-d-3"><a>Remove</a></div>
  </li>
  <li id="parts5" style="display: list-item;" onclick="remove();">
    <div class="col-md-9"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Front Camera</div>
    <div class="col-d-3"><a>Remove</a></div>
  </li>
</div>

<div id="total">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-6">Repair time</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">170 mins</div>
    <input type="hidden" id="minutes_parts" value="170">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-6">Discount</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">£0.00</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-6">Total</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">£362</div>
    <input type="hidden" id="price_parts" value="362">
  </div>
</div>
```

So, i am directly remove the div on clicking each li elements.